# Cyclotomic Polynomial Proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials, cyclotomic-fields

I am trying to understand this proof for the nth cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n(x)$ having integer coefficients, given in Fraleigh’s 7th edition A First Course in Abstract Algebra. The proof assumes $K$ is the splitting field of $x^n-1 \in F[x]$ where $\mathrm{char} F$ does not divide $n$.

“Since an automorphism of the Galois group $G(K/F)$ must permute the primitive nth roots of unity, we see that $\Phi_n(x)$ is left fixed under every element of $G(K/F)$ regarded as extended in the natural way to $K[x]$. Thus $\Phi_n(x) \in F[x]$. In particular, for $F = \mathbf{Q}$, $\Phi_n(x) \in \mathbf{Q}[x]$, and $\Phi_n(x)$ is a divisor of $x^n - 1$. Thus over $\mathbf{Q}$, we must actually have $\Phi_n(x) \in \mathbf{Z}[x]$, by Theorem 23.11.”

Theorem 23.11 asserts the following:

“If $f(x) \in \mathbf{Z}[x]$, then $f(x)$ factors into a product of two polynomials of lower degrees $r$ and $s$ in $\mathbf{Q}[x]$ if and only if it has such a factorization with polynomials of the same degrees $r$ and $s$ in $\mathbf{Z}[x]$.”

Why must it be that $\Phi_n(x) \in \mathbf{Z}[x]$? I understand why $\Phi_n(x)$ is in $\mathbf{Q}[x]$, since the automorphism take the set of multiplicative order $n$ elements to
itself. All I understand from this is that Theorem 23.11 shows there exists a polynomial in $\mathbf{Z}[x]$ that divides $x^n - 1$ of degree $\phi(n)$. For example, $\frac{1}{2}(x-1)$ divides $(x-1)(x-2)$ in $\mathbf{Q}[x]$ but obviously $\frac{1}{2}(x-1) \notin \mathbf{Z}[x]$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In the case you're applying the theorem to, $f,r,s$ are monic.

Comment: Since $x^n - 1$ is monic, the multiple of $\Phi_n(x)$ that has all integer coefficients must be monic as well.  But $\Phi_n(x)$ *is* monic, so $\Phi_n(x)$ is that multiple that has all integer coefficients.

Comment: @JosephCamacho Thanks for the comment. I don’t think I understand your argument in general. I don’t know what you mean by “*the* multiple of $\Phi_n(x)$ that has all integer coefficients”.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thanks for the response. Yes, but I don’t see why that means $\Phi_n(x)$ must have integer coefficients.

Comment: We know by Theorem 23.11 that there is at least one multiple of $\Phi_n(x)$ that has all integer coefficients and is a divisor of $x^n - 1$ in $\mathbb Z[x]$.  Because $x^n - 1$ is monic, this multiple is unique, which is why I wrote *the* multiple.